ssh disconnect after pledge: filesystem
I try to make work my sftp server. It work well but suddently i get this error : client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe . For all sftp user...
I check the file system rights, sshd config, but i found nothing. I reinstall ssh but don't work.
sshd:
KbdInteractiveAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
PrintMotd no
ChrootDirectory %h
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
Match group sftp
        X11Forwarding no
        AllowTcpForwarding no
        PermitTTY no
        ForceCommand internal-sftp

log:
Authenticated to 127.0.0.1 ([127.0.0.1]:22) using "password".
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 0: new session [client-session] (inactive timeout: 0)
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: filesystem
debug3: client_repledge: enter
debug3: send packet: type 1
client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe
Connection closed.  
Connection closed

